# android start user defined activity on search button pressed @ handset

Tags: android, search, button

I am using following code to start activity when user pressing search button on the handset

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH){
        Util.startActivity(ReviewsDetail.this, KeywordSearch.class);
        return false;
    }else{
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event); 
    }
}
```

But here are few issues with it please look at the following image.

When press search button it first show google search box at the top of activity then start activity which i want to start

[image]

When click on the back button displays empty actiivty
[image]

Comment: Should be `return true;` in the first case.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
 @Override
 public boolean onSearchRequested() {

     // your logic here

     return false;  // don't go ahead and show the search box
 }
```

Comment: i'm glad to hear it. if you're happy with a response, please mark it as 'accepted', by ticking the accept-icon underneath the vote symbols, so that other users can see that this issue has been resolved.

Comment: why is it not recommended to override the search button behavior?!

Comment: That makes no sense - the search button is supposed to be overridden to make searches in your app, otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: I honestly do not remember why I wrote that. I agree it makes no sense; removing...

Answer (score 0):

The Search button and system's search request are both working the same when invoked from any activity of your app. If you want to override it you will have to override it for EVERY activity you want it to work from in the same way. Unfortunately, there is no way to override it "globally", neither a way to subclass/style/theme the default search popup. So sad, google.