# how to open activity when search key pressed android

Tags: android

Hello as the title says, i want to open a custom activity when the search key on the phone is pressed. I have a custom search activity that is using an Autocomplete textview to show suggestions. So i, don't need any searchable.xml, i just want to fire this activity up when the search key is pressed.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: There is an exact same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912947/android-start-user-defined-activity-on-search-button-pressed-handset Plz do always perform an exhaustive search because most probably (especially for such "standard" questions) someone else might have found a solution before :)

Comment: the coincident is funny... he want to implement a custom search for android but didn't use the search functionality on SO... if his user will act the same, he can save some work by didn't implementing it... funny...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the [onSearchRequested()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSearchRequested()) method of Activity class.

```
public boolean onSearchRequested() {

        // Call the custom search activity here.

        return true;
}
```

See Also:

- [Search Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
            //start custome activity
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```