# How to handle hardware search button android?

Tags: android

I am new to android, I have a small doubt regarding how to handle the hardware Keyboard and if I click the search button in any part of my application it should be handled means I need to pass the intent of search activity?

How I can reach this goal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912947/android-start-user-defined-activity-on-search-button-pressed-handset

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this,

```
  @Override
 public boolean onSearchRequested() {
     // your stuff here
     return false; 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

It will also trigger `onKeyDown` with a keyCode of `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH` before calling `onSearchRequested` as stated above

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener for your `EditText` to listen on the Search button as following:

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                //Do some stuff
            }
            //Leave the return value false to hide the SoftKeyboard if it is shown
            return false;
        }
    });
```

For me, it happened before that the softkey search button is detected as `Enter` button not search. That's why I'm ORing them

Comment: Thanks Sami!! It is helped me.